# Textbook of group cohomology and class field theory

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I want to learn group cohomology and class field theory.
My background is the abelian category and homological algebra.
Therefore, books that use the fact that the category of G-module is an abelian category are better for me.

I'd appreciate if you could answer this question!

Comment: [Milne's notes on CFT](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/cft.html)

Comment: I have no idea about class field theory , but I have read the initial part of Brown's Book Cohomology of groups to learn  a bit about homology/Cohomology of groups.

Comment: What is your background on algebraic number theory?

Comment: A nice exposition to class field theory would be Neukirch's algebraic number theory. It utilises an axiomatical approach to class field theory where the arguments are mainly group theoretical, and only the first few cohomology groups are being utilised. For a textbook that mainly utilises the formalism of group cohomology cassels frohlich 's Algebraic number theory is very good too. For a good exposition to group cohomology weibel's introduction to homological algebra is very good, even though it might provide more info than needed. Lang's local fields has a short intro to the cohomology....

Comment: Theory needed for class field theory. I see that Minle's notes have been mentioned already, and that is a great textbook for both.

Comment: Also, a background in homological algebra, say familiarity with the theory of universal delta functors and derived functors would be needed before you get your hands on group cohomology.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am a formalism, so cassels frohlich 's Algebraic The number theory looks interesting. However, I would like to read Milne's notes on CFT first.